# Web3j read all the emitted events of a sinle transaction

Tags: java, ethereum, web3-java

I have a smart contract method "transferFrom" which, at the end, emits an event "EventTransf". From a java program using web3j I call such a method and I obtain the receipt.

```
TransactionReceipt tr=contract.transferFrom(from,to, tk).send();
```

Now, I would read all the emitted events from this method call. I have red about the web3j filter, but I'm only interested in the events emitted inside this call. The code should also work with infura.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I need to use tr.getLogs() and for each Log object, I call

```
  List<Type> args = FunctionReturnDecoder.decode(
              log.getData(), Contract.Event_Type.getParameters());
```